# JavaFX runtime exceptions when running .jar file

Tags: java, javafx, runtimeexception

I have a JavaFX project running perfectly with no exceptions on eclipse IDE. I'm trying to export it into a runnable jar, and then an executable. However, after exporting it into a runnable jar I get multiple exceptions when I run it. These exceptions don't appear when I run the app inside eclipse. They only show up when I run the jar (via command prompt). Here are the exceptions:[image]

[image]

And here are my project files as well as the VM arguments used.

[image]

Comment: You need to replicate those VM arguments when you run it from the command line.

Comment: no screenshots of text please ..

Comment: Click on _Show Command Line_ button (in _Run Configurations_ window) and Eclipse will display another window containing the text of the command that Eclipse uses in order to run your application. Then read about [JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) files in order to understand how to convert the command that Eclipse uses to a command that can launch your JAR.

Comment: Images of text are very hard to read, cannot be searched, cannot be copied, and cannot be understood by sight impaired users.  Please edit your question and paste the stack trace as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add classpath
you need java 15 in cmd
use this in your cmd

```
java --module-path "<path of your javafx lib" --add-modules ";javafx.fxml,javafx.controls" -jar jarfile.jar
```